# DecimalFormat removes zero after dot

Tags: java, android

I want to format user's input and it's okay, but when I try to input zero after dot `DecimalFormat` removes it.
I use the following code:

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
 Number n = df.parse(v);
 amountEdit.setText(df.format(n));
```

Example Input/Output:

9.0 -> 9.

9.9 -> 9.9

9.90 -> 9.9

It removes zeros!

**EDIT:**

I have `EditText` with `TextChangedListener`
The idea is to format user's input like `999 999 999.99` (this is max value).

```
  amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (data.document.isPaymentPossible) {

                if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())) || s.toString().contains(".")) {
                    hasDot = true;
                } else {
                    hasDot = false;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString().replaceAll("\\.", ",");

            if (string.equals(",") || string.equals(".")) {
                amountEdit.setText("");
                return;
            }

            amountEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            payCustomAmount.setEnabled(amountEdit.getText().length() != 0);

            try {

                if (string.contains(",")) {
                    try {
                        String afterDot = string.split(",")[1];
                        if (afterDot.length() > 2) {
                            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
                            Number n = df.parse(string);
                            amountEdit.setText(df.format(n).replace(",", "."));
                            amountEdit.setSelection(amountEdit.getText().length());
                            amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
                            showOverPaidText();
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            SysUtils.logf("PaymentOptions input: " + s + "Exception: " + e);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (string.length() > 11) {
                        string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
                        Number n = dfnd.parse(string);
                        amountEdit.setText(dfnd.format(n));
                        amountEdit.setSelection(amountEdit.getText().length());
                        showOverPaidText();
                        amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                int inilen, endlen;
                inilen = amountEdit.getText().length();

                String v = string.replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");

                int cp = amountEdit.getSelectionStart();
                if (hasDot) {
                    Number n = df.parse(v);
                    String ss = df.format(n).replace(",", ".");
                    amountEdit.setText(ss);
                } else {
                    Number n = dfnd.parse(v);
                    amountEdit.setText(dfnd.format(n));
                }
                endlen = amountEdit.getText().length();
                int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
                if (sel > 0 && sel <= amountEdit.getText().length()) {
                    amountEdit.setSelection(sel);
                } else {
                    amountEdit.setSelection(amountEdit.getText().length() - 1);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
                showOverPaidText();
                amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);

                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    SysUtils.logf("PaymentOptions input: " + s + "Exception: " + e);
                }
                return;
            }
            showOverPaidText();
            amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
            return;
        }
    });
```

My `onCreate` contains:

```
df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

    hasDot = false;
```

Comment: Your example input does not contain dot, it's semicolon ?

Comment: edited my answer @CagriYalcin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It removes zeros!

Well yes, it would - you've specifically used `.##` which means "only include digits if they're significant". If you want to *always* have at least one decimal place, use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.0#");
```

If you always want to have two decimal places, use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

You should probably consider how you want 0.5 to be formatted, too. Do you want "0.5" or ".5"?

Comment: Sure, I want 0.5 too

Comment: @ManOfWar: In that case, you probably want "#,##0.00". Basically, you need to read the `DecimalFormat` documentation more carefully.

Comment: When I place "." my edit text fills with 00, like 5.00 and I could not add other numbers.
Sure, I m going to read it

Comment: @ManOfWar: In that case, it sounds like your overall approach (which you haven't fully described or shown) is flawed. All we can see is your input and existing output, which I've explained here.

Comment: @ManOfWar: It's a question, not an answer - but fundamentally you need to rethink your approach. Rather than me wade through 100 lines of code, ask yourself what you *want* the result to be in each case, and whether you believe that's feasible with a single format...

Comment: Okay, I will try another way and leave my results here!

Answer (score 0):

'#' means include this digit if it matters and since `9,0 == 9`, the formatting removes it.

If you need a minimum of two digits after decimal then you should replace to format as:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```